# Debugging vs code python function app with custom docker image

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I am not able to understand the right configuration to debug python function app using custom docker image from VS Code. I have attached the launch and task.json.

Steps:

Build Docker Image
Run Docker Image built in prior step and launch debugger
I did not find any documentation specific to python function apps, there are examples of flask apps.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python

Launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
      
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - General",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                  {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/home/site/wwwroot"
                  }
                ],
                "projectType": "general"
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build",
            "platform": "python",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "tag": "test:latest",
                "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "pull": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "platform": "python",
            "dependsOn": [
                "docker-build"
            ],
            "python": {
                "debugPort": 5678,
                "file": "./document-processor-func/__init__.py"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article,](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/debug-python-docker/) you can use the following `launch.json`:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
```